# AssertJ: Assert if list is sorted inversely or in descending order

Tags: java, list, sorting, assertj

I'm using AssertJ for my tests and I noticed there's a method for checking if a `List<T>` is sorted:

```
public static <T> void sorted(final List<T> actual) {
    try {
        assertThat(actual).isSorted();
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check if the list is sorted in descending order?

I know guava provides `Ordering.natural().reverse().isOrdered(values)` but I want to take advantage of AssertJ's assert messages as it really helps a lot in debugging e.g.

```
group is not sorted because element 5:
 <"4000366190001391">
is not less or equal than element 6:
 <"4000206280001394">
group was:
 <["4000206280001363",
    "4000206280001364",
    "4000206280001365",
    "4000206280001373",
    "4000206280001388",
    "4000366190001391",
    "4000206280001394",
    "4000366190001401",
    "4000206280001403",
    "4000206280001405",
     ....]>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. There's also the method [`isSortedAccordingTo`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/ArraySortedAssert.html#isSortedAccordingTo(java.util.Comparator)) which takes a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

You'll need to change the generic type parameter to `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, i.e. a type which has a natural ordering. Then `Comparator.reverseOrder()` can say be used to assert that it should be the reverse *of it's natural ordering*. Without that constraint, you'd be trying to reverse some unknown/unspecified ordering, which results in a compiler error.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sorted(final List<T> actual) {
    try {
        assertThat(actual).isSortedAccordingTo(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
assertThat(downloadHistory).extracting("downloadedAt", LocalDateTime.class)
                .isSortedAccordingTo(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```